# How to get a value on mouse click?

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

As an example if I click on Canada cell I need to get the "Canada value".

Comment: Have you attempted anything at this point? You should not just post a problem here and ask us to write all the code for you. This won't help you learn, and wastes time as we try to guess what approach you're taking.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion buddy

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation for `click` and obtain the text content of the element you have clicked. For instance:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
    alert(event.target.innerText); 
}, false);
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsbin.com/tuqajanifu/edit?html,js,output)</kbd>